# How are we able to create objects of CountDownTimer class which is abstract

Tags: android

I am new to android and currently working with timers.

From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer I can understand that CountDownTimer is an abstract class.

From my understanding of abstract class we cannot create an object of an abstract class and generally if we try to create an object of an abstract class the IDE will show an error.

But the below code which I tried did not show any error.

I checked on stackoverflow and other sites to see I was able to create an object of CountDownTimer but could not find any explanation.

Below is excerpts from my code which is working.

```
public void startTimer() {
   CountDownTimer c =  new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timerTextView.setText(Long.toString(millisUntilFinished / 1000) 
+ "s");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            playAgain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            result.setText("Done");
        }
    };
   c.start();
}
```

Any explanation on how I am able to create the object of CountDownTimer class would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code is actually doing is creating an inner anonymous class that extends CountDownTimer, implements it and creates an object of that "new" class.

CountDownTimer is abstract, so yes, you can't just do 'new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000)' alone.

But your code opens it up and implements both 'onTick' and 'onFinish' functions (which are the only abstract functions in the CountDownTimer class.

Comment: Thanks, that explanation was helpful.